# Is there a performance improvement if using an object initializer, or is it asthetic?

Tags: c#

So, the comparison would be between:

```
MyClass foo = new MyClass();
foo.Property1 = 4;
foo.Property2 = "garfield";
```

and

```
MyClass foo = new MyClass { Property1 = 4, Property2 = "garfield" };
```

Is it syntactic sugar, or is there actually some kind of performance gain (however minute it's likely to be?)

Comment: Wow, this one really attracted the heavy-hitters, 200k rep in first 4 answers.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's actually potentially *very, very* slightly slower to use an object initializer than to call a constructor and then assign the properties, as it has one extra assignment:

```
MyClass foo = new MyClass();
foo.Property1 = 4;
foo.Property2 = "garfield";
```

vs

```
MyClass tmp = new MyClass();
tmp.Property1 = 4;
tmp.Property2 = "garfield";
MyClass foo = tmp;
```

The properties are all assigned before the reference is assigned to the variable. This difference is a *visible* one if it's reusing a variable:

```
using System;

public class Test
{
    static Test shared;

    string First { get; set; }

    string Second
    {
        set
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Setting second. shared.First={0}",
                              shared == null ? "n/a" : shared.First);
        }
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        shared = new Test { First = "First 1", Second = "Second 1" };
        shared = new Test { First = "First 2", Second = "Second 2" };        
    }
}
```

The output shows that in the second line of `Main`, when `Second` is being set (after `First`), the value of `shared.First` is still "First 1" - i.e. `shared` hasn't been assigned the new value yet.

As Marc says though, you'll almost certainly never actually spot a difference.

Anonymous types are guaranteed to use a constructor - the form is given in section 7.5.10.6 of the C# 3 language specification.

Comment: I had a similar one earlier with MP3 files. Your comment has prompted me to leave a similar comment...

Answer (score 7):

It is **entirely sugar** for standard types. For anonymous types, you may find that it uses a constructor behind the scenes, but since the initializer syntax is the **only** way of assigning them, it is a moot point.

This involves a few more calls than, say, a specific constructor - but I'd be **amazed** if you ever saw a difference as a result. Just use initializer syntax - it is friendlier ;-o

Answer (score 2):

No there is no performance improvement.  Under the hood the compiler will generated assignments to the same properties and fields.  It will look just like your expanded version.

Answer (score 2):

I'ts syntactic sugar and the compiler generates the same exact IL as it did before object initializers were introduced in .NET 3.5

Comment: Sounds like a sweeping assumption. Proof or citation?