# Are there performance penalties for named/optional parameters for constructors?

Tags: c#, performance, constructor

So would:

```
public Car(string color = "red", topSpeed = 180)
{
  carColor = color;
  carTopSpeed = topSpeed;
}
```

be faster or slower to do than constructor chaining to get the values to carColor and carTopSpeed?
I understand on a desktop environment the performance will almost always be negligible, but:

I would like to know for mobile game development where all the little things count in performance.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1215137/is-there-a-performance-improvement-if-using-an-object-initializer-or-is-it-asth

Comment: @Ofiris: Not quite the same. This question talks about named / option - that question is about intializers vs constructor.

Comment: Your are correct, got confused for a second.

Comment: Please, do not include information about a language used in a question title unless it wouldn't make sense without it. Tags serve this purpose.

Comment: Ah, my apologies! @OndrejJanacek

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No performance penalties.

In fact, optional parameters do not exist at runtime. They are a compiler trick, i.e. the compiler puts in the full parameter set.

There even is an explicit warning to not use them (one I totally disagree with) because if you change the default value, then the old compiled code does not use the new values.

[Performance differences between overloading or optional parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19582920/performance-differences-between-overloading-or-optional-parameters)

has exactlyx the same question.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no performance penalty at all. When the compiler recognizes you're using a constructor with default parameters it automatically inserts those values into the compiled code.

Calling `var car = new Car()` is compiled exactly as if you called it this way:

```
var car = new Car("red", 180);
```